# python Huffman coding cost

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make code which calculates the cost of prefix code in Huffman coding.
I made half of the code right now,

```
import heapq

f = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

T=[]

for i in range(len(f)):
    heapq.heappush(T,(f[i],str(i)))

while len(T)>1:
    a=heapq.heappop(T)
    b=heapq.heappop(T)
    heapq.heappush(T,(a[0]+b[0],'('+a[1]+' '+b[1]+')' ) )

print(T)
```

and it's quite working well as the result comes out like this:[(117, '(((2 9) (((5 1) 3) 0)) ((6 4) ((10 8) 7)))')]
However, I have trouble making the cost, I found out "(" makes +1 in the depth of heap, and ) makes -1. And when it meets the number, it stops and I can just simply multiply the number and the depth.

```
for i in T:
    if i == "(":
        temp = temp+1
    if i == ")":
        temp == temp -1
    if T[i]!="(" or ")":
        temp * T[i] = cost
```

is this right to approach this side of view?

Comment: Are those numbers frequencies? What is the encoded data?

Comment: yes, my inputs are frequencies. and I don't understand about encoded data.